# Datetimes changing from WebLogic SOAP service to WCF application

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, timezone, weblogic

I'm from Chile and the time zone is currently set to GMT -3:00. My platforms are configured with these timezone settings:

> Oracle database: GMT -3:00
>
> WebLogic server: GMT -3:00
>
> Windows 7 client: GMT -3:00

I'm getting strange results when performing this query:

> 1st query: Date = 26/03/08 06:10:00,000000000
>
> 2nd query: Date = 24/05/13 18:48:00,000000000

I can see (via SOAP UI) that WebLogic returns this result:

```
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:fobpgGestacionesPorFichaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nucleo.alemana.cl/">
         <fobpgGestacionesPorFichaResult>
            <gestaciones>
               <controles>7</controles>
               <esGestaTerminada>1</esGestaTerminada>
               <fechaPrimerControl>2007-10-05T00:00:00-03:00</fechaPrimerControl>
               <fechaTermino>2008-03-26T06:10:00-03:00</fechaTermino>
               ..............^ date #1 is here

               <fur>2007-08-05T00:00:00-03:00</fur>
               <furOp>2007-08-05T00:00:00-03:00</furOp>
               <gesdaFechaCreacion>2015-08-19T14:58:41.903-03:00</gesdaFechaCreacion>
               <gesnuIdGesta>45087</gesnuIdGesta>
               <gesnuNroGesta>1</gesnuNroGesta>
               <rnMayorPeso>0</rnMayorPeso>
            </gestaciones>
            <gestaciones>
               <controles>12</controles>
               <esGestaTerminada>1</esGestaTerminada>
               <fechaPrimerControl>2012-10-11T00:00:00-03:00</fechaPrimerControl>
               <fechaTermino>2013-05-24T18:48:00-03:00</fechaTermino>
               ..............^ date #2  is here

               <fur>2012-08-27T00:00:00-03:00</fur>
               <furOp>2012-08-27T00:00:00-03:00</furOp>
               <gesdaFechaCreacion>2015-08-19T14:58:28.071-03:00</gesdaFechaCreacion>
               <gesnuIdGesta>45086</gesnuIdGesta>
               <gesnuNroGesta>2</gesnuNroGesta>
               <rnMayorPeso>1980</rnMayorPeso>
            </gestaciones>
         </fobpgGestacionesPorFichaResult>
      </ns2:fobpgGestacionesPorFichaResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

However, when my client WPF application connects to the WebLogic service and retrieves the above data, I get these values (in debug mode):

**1st date response**

[image: 1st date response]

This is one hour ahead (7:10) of what I'd expect (6:10).

**2nd date response**

[image: 2nd date response]

This is as expected (18:48)!

I'm not sure what's going on here. Why are these results inconsistent?

Comment: Hi F.Rojas, I edited your question to clean up the grammar and formatting. If you feel that I changed the meaning of your question, feel free to roll back. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The SOAP response looks correct. Can you deserialize to a `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` and inspect what timezone data it thinks it has?

Comment: i change System.DateTime for System.DateTimeOffset  in ServiceReference setter. The returning data for all dates are as follows:
01-01-0001 0:00:00 +00:00

Comment: A blunt guess: Can it have something to do with daylight savings time? In 2008, Chile had DST until March 29. If you have the possibility to fast forward the date to, say April 1, and see if the problem still is there.

Comment: yes, the date is displayed correctly when changing from 26-03-2008 to 30-03-2008, which is what is causing this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before and it really puzzled me. .NET automatically changes `DateTime` values when serialising/deserializing XML based on the machine's time zone configuration. It is .NET trying to be helpful, but is not an expected behaviour so tends to cause a lot of confusion.

The best way to handle `DateTime` in any application is to store UTC date times and then display them in local format on the client.

But, a quicker fix that does not involve converting all of your date times to UTC would be this:

Try changing your `DateTime`s so that `DateTimeKind` is unspecified, the XML serializer will NOT try to convert them. For example, this code will convert a date to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(oldDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

You can see this long Microsoft guidance on [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx) for more information.